# Vertically center unknown height div with scrolling content

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to make a lightbox-like window which has a known-height titlebar, and a content area of unknown height.

I am using [a floating pseudoelement with `vertical-align: middle`](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) to vertically center it. This works perfectly...when the window's height is smaller than the viewport's.

(copy-pasted code from CSS-tricks)

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

**My problem is that I don't know how to limit the window height and maintain vertical centering when the scrolling content becomes taller than the viewport.**

If the window had no titlebar and inner content area, this would be easy to achieve by applying a `max-height` and `overflow: auto` to the window element. But I would like a titlebar, and I would like the scrollbar to only appear in the content area of the window, as in this image:

[image]

I can set `overflow: auto` on the content area, but `max-height` set in percent (which I need, as I can't assume the user's viewport height) seems to be ignored.

Is this layout possible without using JS?

[Here's a demo to play with](http://jsbin.com/olajih/6/edit). The window's overflowing below the viewport, although if you remove enough content (to make it shorter than the viewport), it will be vertically centered.

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Comment: I think so, but I think I had to resort to JS. It was so long ago I don't remember now. The demo in your answer does not show the div as vertically centered though, so it doesn't answer the question, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, the viewport I was working on at the time had it vertically centered, hadn't tested it on a larger screen. I updated my solution to work as you desired (:

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the demo still doesn't answer the question.  `height:75%` is not "unknown height".  If I remove most of the content (leave a few lines only) then the window won't shrink to fit the content; it'll remain at 75% height. If I use `max-height` instead, the window doesn't behave properly when there's lots of content.

Comment: Alright, I updated it one final time with a line of javascript to make is function exactly like that you want

Answer (score 1):

Give `bg` `height:100%;` and give `window` your desired percentage height [**Updated Demo**](http://jsbin.com/olajih/28/edit)

```
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  height:100%; /* The important part you were missing */
}
.window {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height:75%; /* The height you desire */
}
.bg:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;  
}
.titlebar {
  height: 30px; /* arbitrary value but height is known and static */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
.window .content {
  margin-top: 30px; /* same abritrary value as titlebar height */
  height:calc(100% - 60px); /* I would think that this would be 30px, 
                               but in practice it needed 60px... */
  overflow:auto;
}
```

On a side note, you should include all the CSS in demos in the same spot, I was perplexed with why my method wasn't working properly until I noticed the padding added in the far bottom of the demo

**Edit**

Apparently what you want to do is impossible in pure CSS because you have to give a `height` to `window`other than `auto`. So, I added one line of javascript and it works exactly as how you require

```
document.getElementsByClassName('window')[0].style.height = 
    document.getElementsByClassName('window')[0].offsetHeight + "px";
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsbin.com/olajih/31/edit)

Answer (score -3):

```
!important
```

in any element is possible solve this.

Comment: `!important` on what? What conflicting rules am I trying to override?